# How do I make the new Google calendar event text wrap around using CSS?

Tags: html, css, google-calendar-api, greasemonkey, word-wrap

I can't read the full title of my Google Calendar events, because they're truncated to fit in the day box. And so a printout isn't as useful as it could be.

There used to be a greasemonkey plugin that changed the CSS to fix this, but Google have redesigned the calendar, and now the titles overlap each other and can't be read properly.

What CSS do I now need to add to the page to make the event titles wrap nicely? This is the existing code of the Greasemonkey plugin:

```
function buildStyle()
{
    var st = "div.rb-n, span, nobr { white-space: normal; }";
    var dochead = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
    var stEl = document.createElement("style");
    stEl.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
    stEl.innerHTML = st;
    dochead.appendChild(stEl);
}

window.addEventListener("load", function(e) {
    buildStyle();
}, false);
```

Here is the Greasemonkey plugin itself: http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/97755 -- It can be seen working correctly if you revert Google calendar to 'classic view', but fails to work for the new view.

UPDATE:

I've saved off an example of a Google calendar, showing two test events:

- http://pastebin.com/wx5Qm8yx - the HTML code for the calendar
- http://pastebin.com/UZnLp2Pj - The existing stylesheet, rename this to style.css

Comment: I don't use Google calendar and a quick check shows the text that I tried wrapping.  Save one of the offending pages to your harddrive, sanitize any incriminating text without changing the HTML structure and post that to http://pastebin.com/ . Then we can help pick the right CSS selector(s).

Comment: @BrockAdams Okay, have done that.

Comment: Your paste bin links are dead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the page sample provided, you would use these styles:

```
.rb-n {
    white-space: normal !important;
}
.te {
    overflow: inherit !important;
    white-space: normal !important;
}
```

---

**Note:**

1. If you are just changing styles, then it is far superior to use
   [Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/stylish/).

   Stylish is faster; Page-changes are easier/faster to maintain; Changes apply without any flicker or delay; and often, someone has already posted much of what you want at [Userstyles.org](http://userstyles.org/).
2. Likewise, you do not need to use all that JS to add styles in Greasemonkey.  Use the [GM_addStyle](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_addStyle) function:

   ```
   GM_addStyle ( "                                 \
       .rb-n {                                     \
           white-space:    normal !important;      \
       }                                           \
       .te {                                       \
           overflow:       inherit !important;     \
           white-space:    normal !important;      \
       }                                           \
   " );
   ```
3. Google changes their pages rapidly and without warning.  [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) can help determine new changes, and CSS workarounds, as they appear.

Comment: Thanks, this is a good answer. Although the solution you gave doesn't work will  in my real calendar because all the events overlap, you've given me plenty of leads so I can take this further.

Comment: Well, glad it helped some.  I couldn't duplicate the issue in calendar (which I don't use), but you could post another question, if needed -- with file-saves of the HTML/CSS showing the new overlap problem.

Answer (score 0):

I used a [different tutorial](http://thedetaildept.com.au/2012/08/05/making-a-printable-calendar-in-google-calendars/) and combined the CSS found there with the S[tylish extension for chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe?hl=en). I have copied the [original CSS](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/minimalist-google-calendar/iF5VUyXxhN4/discussion) here for convenience and historical reference. A big thanks to Jodie Miners for her hard work.

```
.rb-ni, .rb-n {
border:none;
display: inline-table; 
white-space: pre-wrap;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.st-c-pos > div[style] {
border:none !important;}

.st-dtitle-nonmonth {
color:lightgray;
font-size: 10px !important;
}

.st-dtitle{
font-size:14px;
font-weight:bold;
}

.date-top{
font-weight:bold;
font-size:20px;
}

.st-dtitle-today {
border-color: #DDD !important;
background-color: #FFF !important;
}

.st-bg-today, .st-bg-td-first, .st-bg-td-last {
background-color: #FFF !important;
border-color: #DDD !important;
}

@media print  { .noprint  { display: none; } }
@media print { .noprint { display: inline !important; }
#funbox {display:none !important;}
 }


#topLeftNavigation{
left: -10px !important;
}
.applogo{
display:none;
}
#gb {display:none}
#topRightNavigation {display:none}
```

Be sure to apply to URLs starting with 'https://www.google.com/calendar/'.