# CSS for Google Calendar word wrap long event titles in month view

Tags: css, google-calendar-api, stylish

When looking at Google Calendar in month view, the event titles are only shown on a single line by default. Titles longer than one line are cut off by default.

I'd like to add some custom CSS via the [Stylish](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe?hl=en) plugin for Chrome to make long event titles wrap nicely.

Here's what I have currently, as suggested by [this StackOverflow from 2011](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8236628/3465785):

```
table div div {
  overflow: inherit !important;
  white-space: normal !important;
}
```

This does make the event titles wrap, but if there is more than one event on the same day, then they overlap each other. So I need to find a way to expand the height of the table cell as well.

What CSS do I need?

Answer (score 3):

That works for me!

```
table div div {
height:inherit!important; 
overflow: inherit !important;
white-space: normal !important;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps something has changed at Google since 2014. ;-)   Neither of these snippets of code cause title text to wrap when I add them via Stylish.